# how can I download TARGET-AML from TCGA with TCGA biolinks

Tags: r, installation, package, gtsummary, r-devel

I was trying to install the package gtsummary but I am unable to install it and I keep getting the following error:

Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

I downloaded the package from:

r-devel: gtsummary_1.7.2.zip
and loaded it from the directory. Other packages from the directory can be installed but just not this one.

Is the package corrupt or could there be any other error?

I would really be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance